# communication with my bot discord doesnt work

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello im trying to communicate with my bot discord but its doesnt answer
the bot is online but no answer here the following code :

```
import discord


client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
client.run("token")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "ping":
        await message.channel.send("pong")
```

Comment: yeah because if u researched before asking that question u would know u need `message_content` intent enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the message content intent.
add this in your code under your intents definitions

```py
intents.message_content = True
```

then head to the [developer dashboard](https://discord.com/developers/applications)
and enable the `Message Content` at the `Privileged Intents` after that your code should work ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Having your bot to answer to sent messages requires the **message_content** intent.

With `intents=discord.Intents.default()` following intents are DISABLED:

- self.presences (= having your bot to see rich presence, e.g. what game's being played)
- self.members (= having your bot to see the user of a guild)
- self.message_content (= having your bot to see the content of messages)

You can now enable all mentioned intents or only specific intents. If you want to send a message, in response to a sent message, you need the intent `self.message_content`.

You can also add all intents to avoid any problems with them in the future (Note that after a certain amount of Discord servers you need to apply to use all privileged intents.)

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

You should consider activating the intents:
Visit the [developer portal](https://discord.dev/) > choose your app > Privileged Gateway Intents.

For further programming in Discord.py, consider reading the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html), as there is a new version of Discord.py.

Answer (score 1):

The `message_content` intent mentioned above is necessary, but it's not the only thing wrong here.

When you call `client.run()`, nothing below it will execute until the client goes down. This means that your `on_message` event is never created. `client.run()` should be the very last line in your file.